# how i can figure out why Console log is not working in website

Tags: javascript, jquery

below you can see console.log is not printing anything, tried everything that i can like defining and enabling debugger mode.

[image: Console not working]

Website Link : https://oxaleather.com/products/iphone-14-plus-leather-wallet-case

does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: *"does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?"* What is there to fix? Is it your site? If so, remove your code that's mucking about with the `console` object, as that's clearly not the default `console.log`. If not, then what (again) is it you need to fix?

Comment: Use `console.dir` - it does what console.log now does before console.log was changed to do what console.log now does.

Answer (score -2):

if you just type `console.log` (not `console.log()` ) you can see there is native code in output.

```
ƒ log() { [native code] }
```

it mean's the console.log function is not rewriten by developer.

Comment: That's precisely the opposite of what `[native code]` implies.

Comment: You have some typos in your answer:  if you see `[native code` then it means the console.log function has not been rewritten by a developer.

Comment: @freedomn-m — The concept isn't sound.  If it *had* been rewritten then it would explain why `console.log("hi")` didn't log *hi*, but since it hasn't, it doesn't, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Quentin I just meant checking for console.log as a first step - if it had been rewritten then it would identify the rewrite.   Doesn't answer the question either way.